# how do i use multiple certificates on the same computer?

Tags: iphone, signing

I have two certificates on my mac: one is team agent, the other is admin.

I usually use the admin one to develop, but I want also be able to use the team agent cert 
for ad-hoc builds.

How can I achieve this? AFAIK importing both certs and priv keys does not work :(

It seems that xCode only recognizes the admin cert.

thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every profile there are two file 1.distribution certificate and 2. provisioning profile ... double click on both ... next for your convenience I tried to show things graphically follow the steps

1.Open your project and select the xcode file and click on the info icon else select the file and press ALT + CMD + E

[image]

2.Next select the configuration tab and select `Release` from the list

[image]

3.Duplicate it and name it as you wanted like `Adhoc`

[image]

4. Now click on the Build tab and select your mode from the list

[image]

[image]

5.Now you are looking on a dictionary having all the setting for this mode so look for the key as shown in figure

[image]

6.Select the profile you want to set form the drop down .. you'll see your profile name which you selected before

[image]

7.Now repeat same for the product file which you can access form the file view on left of xCode

[image]

8.Now all the settings required is done .... so for every time you want to switch between settings you just need to do this

[image]

and select the mode that you want

[image]